# send mail php without senders email shown to the reciever

Tags: magento, php

I have a client requirement where an email needs to be sent (and replied to) to/from the site admin by the customer but the email addresses should not be shared.

Is there a way in PHP mail() to hide email address being sent to the receiver but the receiver should still be able to reply to the sender.

I have seen it on a few websites. How do they do it?

One more question, my Magento website is loading OPC page very very slowly, is there a fix to it?

Answer (score 1):

are you referring to:

```
$headers = "From: no-reply@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: validemail@domain.com\r\n";
```

so when the person recieves the email they see its from "no-reply" but if they decide to reply it goes to validemail@domain.com

Comment: If you click reply, don't you see the reply-to address?

Comment: It doesn't work for me as the receiver can still see the sender's address in the 'To:' field when he clicks Reply!

Comment: @trideceth12 Yes, and that's what I do not want the sender to see. That's the whole point, not sharing the email addresses but still be able to email each other. Is this possible?

Comment: actually here's the same question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912529/hide-email-address-using-mail-function-in-php

Comment: @Andres right, it cannot be done. I'll have to device another way. Thanks but